# pass string from inputfield to function fails - GTK c-language

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have one issue with gtk in c . I tried to follow the tutorial but I am not able to pass a text-entry to a function when one clicks on the button in the widget.

The code compiles fine but when I press the button I get several warnings and the string from text-entry that was supposed to be printed are null

What did I do wrong?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>


 static GtkWidget *asset_label;
 static GtkWidget *frame;
 static GtkWidget *entry;

 static void entry_Submit(GtkWidget *widget, GtkWidget *entry)
 {
    const gchar *text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY (entry));
    printf ("Result: %s\n", text);

    gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(asset_label));
    asset_label = gtk_label_new (text);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), asset_label);

    gtk_widget_show_all(frame);

 }



 static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
 {
     gtk_main_quit ();
 }



 static void initialize_window(GtkWidget* window)
 {
   gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"My Window"); //Set window title
   gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 400, 200); //Set default size for the window
   g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL); //End application when close button clicked

 }

 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   GtkWidget *window,*table,*label, *button;
   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);


   //Create the main window
   window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   initialize_window(window);


    /* Create a 1x2 table */
    table = gtk_table_new (3, 3, TRUE);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);


   /* create a new label. */
   label = gtk_label_new ("Enter some text:" );
   //gtk_misc_set_alignment (GTK_MISC (label), 0, 0);
   gtk_table_set_homogeneous(GTK_TABLE (table), TRUE);
   gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), label, 1, 2, 0, 1);


   //create a text box
   entry = gtk_entry_new ();
   //gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY (entry), "");
   gtk_entry_set_max_length (GTK_ENTRY (entry),0);
   gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), entry, 0, 1, 0, 1);



   button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Calculate");
   g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (entry_Submit), entry);
   gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), button, 0, 2, 1, 2);



   //gtk_widget_show (button);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

   gtk_main ();
   return 0;
 }
```

And when the button is clicked I get this result:

```
 Result: (null)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in the callback or the way you are registering the callback (as fixing either one of them should fix your problem).
By default the `clicked` callback takes `GtkButton` as the first parameter and `gpointer` data as the second. By using `g_signal_connect_swapped` you are saying that in the callback function, the parameters will be swapped i.e., the first parameter will be `gpointer` data (`GtkEntry` in your code) and second `GtkButton`. But in your callback function you are treating second parameter `entry` which is in fact `GtkButton` as `GtkEntry`. Either use `g_signal_connect` instead of `g_signal_connect_swapped` or use the first parameter `widget` as `GtkEntry` in your callback function.
Side note: Regarding the warning, if the code which you have posted is the full code then in the callback function `entry_Submit` during first execution `asset_label` is null and thus `gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(asset_label));` will throw a warning. Also, `frame` is unassigned before use in the callback function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!!! I will look into this as soon as possible (tomorrow) - and if it works - accept the answer :)

Comment: do you have time to look at another issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937516/how-to-send-multiple-entrys-to-function-gtk